# How to invoke a Linux shell command from Java

Tags: java, shell, command-line

I am trying to execute some Linux commands from Java using redirection (>&) and pipes (|). How can Java invoke `csh` or `bash` commands?

I tried to use this:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("shell command");
```

But it's not compatible with redirections or pipes.

Comment: `cat` and `csh` don’t have anything to do with one another.

Comment: i can understand the question for other commands, but for cat: why the hell don't you just read in the file?

Comment: Everyone gets this wrong first time - Java's exec() does not use the underlying system's shell to execute the command (as kts points out).  The redirection and piping are features of a real shell and are not available from Java's exec().

Comment: stevendick: Thank you very much, I was getting problems because of redirection and piping!

Comment: System.exit(0) is not inside conditional checking if process is done, so it will always exit without outputting errors. Never write conditionals without braces, to avoid exactly this sort of mistake.

Comment: This is not an answer to this question.

Comment: Check here for Runtime exec Pitfalls: http://www.javaworld.com/article/2071275/core-java/when-runtime-exec---won-t.html

Answer (score 110, accepted):

exec does not execute a command in your shell

try

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"csh","-c","cat /home/narek/pk.txt"});
```

instead.

EDIT::
I don't have csh on my system so I used bash instead. The following worked for me

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"bash","-c","ls /home/XXX"});
```

Comment: @Narek. Sorry about that. I fixed it by removing the extra \" 's Apparently they aren't needed. I don't have csh on my system, but it works with bash.

Comment: As others has mentioned this should be independent wether you have csh or bash, isn't it?

Comment: @Narek. It should, but I don;'t know how csh handles arguments.

Comment: @Stephan Actually it does if you remember to escape them correctly =/

Comment: Thank you. This worked. Actually I used "sh" instead of "csh".

Comment: **Warning: this solution will very likely run into the typical problem of it hanging because you didn't read its output and error streams.** For example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8595748/java-runtime-exec

Answer (score 33):

Use ProcessBuilder to separate commands and arguments instead of spaces. This should work regardless of shell used:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Test {

    public static void main(final String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        //Build command 
        List<String> commands = new ArrayList<String>();
        commands.add("/bin/cat");
        //Add arguments
        commands.add("/home/narek/pk.txt");
        System.out.println(commands);

        //Run macro on target
        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(commands);
        pb.directory(new File("/home/narek"));
        pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
        Process process = pb.start();

        //Read output
        StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder();
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
        String line = null, previous = null;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
            if (!line.equals(previous)) {
                previous = line;
                out.append(line).append('\n');
                System.out.println(line);
            }

        //Check result
        if (process.waitFor() == 0) {
            System.out.println("Success!");
            System.exit(0);
        }

        //Abnormal termination: Log command parameters and output and throw ExecutionException
        System.err.println(commands);
        System.err.println(out.toString());
        System.exit(1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Even after java.util.*; is properly imported I can't get above example to run.

Comment: @Stephan I've updated the example code above to remove the logging statements and variables that were declared outside the pasted code, and it should now compile & run. Feel free to try and let me know how it works out.

Answer (score 16):

Building on @Tim's example to make a self-contained method:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Shell {

    /** Returns null if it failed for some reason.
     */
    public static ArrayList<String> command(final String cmdline,
    final String directory) {
        try {
            Process process = 
                new ProcessBuilder(new String[] {"bash", "-c", cmdline})
                    .redirectErrorStream(true)
                    .directory(new File(directory))
                    .start();

            ArrayList<String> output = new ArrayList<String>();
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
            String line = null;
            while ( (line = br.readLine()) != null )
                output.add(line);

            //There should really be a timeout here.
            if (0 != process.waitFor())
                return null;

            return output;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            //Warning: doing this is no good in high quality applications.
            //Instead, present appropriate error messages to the user.
            //But it's perfectly fine for prototyping.

            return null;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        test("which bash");

        test("find . -type f -printf '%T@\\\\t%p\\\\n' "
            + "| sort -n | cut -f 2- | "
            + "sed -e 's/ /\\\\\\\\ /g' | xargs ls -halt");

    }

    static void test(String cmdline) {
        ArrayList<String> output = command(cmdline, ".");
        if (null == output)
            System.out.println("\n\n\t\tCOMMAND FAILED: " + cmdline);
        else
            for (String line : output)
                System.out.println(line);

    }
}
```

(The test example is a [command that lists all files in a directory and its subdirectories, recursively, in chronological order](https://superuser.com/a/745424/141883).)

By the way, if somebody can tell me why I need four and eight backslashes there, instead of two and four, I can learn something. There is one more level of unescaping happening than what I am counting.

Edit: Just tried this same code on Linux, and there it turns out that I need half as many backslashes in the test command! (That is: the expected number of two and four.) Now it's no longer just weird, it's a portability problem.

Comment: You should ask your question as new StackOverflow question, not as part of your answer.

Comment: Works with two and four on OSX / Oracle java8. Seems there is a problem with your original java environment (which you do not mention the nature of)