# Why can't I run the android emulator? java.io.IOException: error=13, Permission denied

Tags: android

I have installed everything like I was told to by the android website and all I keep getting after I create my avd is:

```
Failed to start emulator: Cannot run program "/home/hevel/eclipse/android-sdk-linux_86//tools/emulator": java.io.IOException: error=13, Permission denied
```

Anybody got any ideas? I'm running `fedora15_x86_64` if that helps.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3085897/permission-denied-error-in-java

Comment: r u playing any mediaplayer or anything u access from sdcard or something like that ?

Comment: @yesterday What JVM is Eclipse running on, or what version of the JVM are you running in Fedora

Answer (score 4):

try to run these commands in terminal: Navigate to your android tools folder (for me it's Android-SDK/tools/), then type:

```
chmod +x emulator
chmod +x ddms
```

Comment: However doing this my problem got solved now my R.java file is not there it contains BuildConfig.java only instead of R.java and i have tried clean and build but none was working .....

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have given the execute permissions for the emulator for the user you are running eclipse as.

Answer (score 0):

go to your directory

```
/home/hevel/eclipse/android-sdk-linux_86//tools/emulator
```

to set permissions

```
chmod +777 emulator
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by adding executable permission to the file"~/sdk/tools"

Open your terminal and

```
chmod +x system file path ~/tools/emulator
```