# java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "pwd.sh": error=13, Permission denied ... How do I get environment variables in Eclipse debug session?

Tags: java, eclipse, java-io

I have a weird problem while trying to execute a system process from within a Java program.  Getting permission denied error:
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "pwd.sh": error=13, Permission denied

Very similar to this:
[Permission denied error in Java for chmod command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3085897/permission-denied-error-in-java)

It is working for me on one machine and not another.  I have tried setting permissions to 777 on the pwd.sh file and no luck.  The problem does not occur when I start the java program as 'user1', but it does occur when I start as root with 'sudo -u user1 java ...'  (Which is what I ultimately need to do.)

So, any ideas what is going on?  Is there a way in Eclipse to check my userid and present working directory before the program is called?

Comment: In Java, you can get the working dir with `System.getProperty("user.dir");`. For the user name use `System.getProperty("user.name");` In Eclipse you can change the working directory in your launch configuration and the user running eclipse is also the one running your program