# how to run unix commands from java

Tags: android

I want to execute some Unix commands from the java code.

I want to run logcat command from java code.

I am using the below code to do this:

```
  Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("logcat -v time -f /mnt/sdcard/abc.txt");
```

The above code is working perfectly.

The same way I want to run some other Unix commands .

I want to run  "WC -l"(read no.of lines in file) command and I want to store it out put in some integer.

Below is the code that I have written for this:

```
 Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("wc -l /mnt/sdcard/abc.txt");
```

But it is throwing below exception.

```
   08-19 05:34:53.457 W/System.err( 1269): java.io.IOException: Error running exec(). Command: [wc, -l, /mnt/sdcard/abc.txt] Working Directory: null Environment: null

   08-19 05:34:53.457 W/System.err( 1269):  at java.lang.ProcessManager.exec(ProcessManager.java:224)

   08-19 05:34:53.457 W/System.err( 1269):  at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:189)

   08-19 05:34:53.457 W/System.err( 1269):  at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:275)

   08-19 05:34:53.457 W/System.err( 1269):  at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:210)
```

Please help me what's the issue in this..

I have a file "abc.txt"  in SD card.

is it possible to execute "WC -l" command from java code of android.

If we can execute Unix commands from java code we can make file operations very easier.

Comment: did you read that post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410741/want-to-invoke-a-linux-shell-command-from-java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here the list of the System /bin in android there is no "wc" sorry

```
am                 check_prereq  dexopt       fsck_msdos    iftop     keystore_cli  mediaserver  netd         ps            rild       service         stagefright     toolbox
applypatch         chmod         df           gdbjithelper  ime       kill          mkdir        netstat      qemud         rm         servicemanager  start           top
applypatch_static  chown         dhcpcd       gdbserver     input     linker        monkey       newfs_msdos  qemu-props    rmdir      setconsole      stop            umount
app_process        cmp           dmesg        getevent      insmod    ln            mount        notify       racoon        rmmod      setprop         surfaceflinger  updater
audioloop          dalvikvm      dnsmasq      getprop       installd  log           mtpd         omx_tests    radiooptions  route      sh              svc             vdc
bmgr               date          dumpstate    gzip          ioctl     logcat        mv           ping         reboot        run-as     showlease       sync            vmstat
bootanimation      dbus-daemon   dumpsys      hd            ionice    logwrapper    nandread     pm           record        schedtest  skia_test       system_server   vold
bugreport          dd            dvz          id            iptables  ls            ndc          pppd         recovery      schedtop   sleep           tc              watchprops
cat                debuggerd     flash_image  ifconfig      keystore  lsmod         netcfg       printenv     renice        sendevent  smd             testid3         wipe
```

Answer (score 1):

wc is not present on android.

```
dev:~ njzk2$ ./adb shell wc
wc: not found
```

However, you can consider opening the file and counting the number of lines from there.

Answer (score 0):

You can **try** `grep` instead.

The following command:

```
$ wc -l filename
```

outputs the equivalent to:

```
$ grep -c '.*' filename
```

The expression `.*` means *any character except line break zero or more times,* which works for lines of every possible size.

*Related:*
https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/25344

**PS:** You can play with and debug regular expressions at https://regexr.com/