# Draw a decision tree with results for an instance in Matlab

Tags: matlab, weka, c4.5

I have created a decision tree in Weka. I now want to calculate a prediction (with this model) in matlab and visualize the result nicely in the tree. But I haven't been able to find a good way to draw the tree and the results from the instance on it.

Should I draw it as a flow chart? is there an out of the box way to do this? Could I calculate C4.5 in Matlab and would it already draw the tree?

Comment: You can use this implementation of tree data structure, which includes plotting: http://tinevez.github.io/matlab-tree/

Answer (score 0):

You can visualize the tree directly from Weka: [Visualizing Weka classification tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9175116/visualizing-weka-classification-tree)

Then, you can ask Weka to print the tree and you can copy and parse the structure elsewhere. Think of the structure as some kind of nested if/then/elses, will be something like this:

```
FeatureLabel-hasPRP <= 0
|   FeatureAnimal-Class <= 0.636364
|   |   FeatureLabel-hasNNP <= 0
|   |   |   v-subject-g-talk <= 0.285714
|   |   |   |   FeatureLabel-hasNN <= 0
|   |   |   |   |   FeatureLabel-hasPOS <= 0
|   |   |   |   |   |   FeatureLabel-dep_head_det_the <= 0: NONACTOR (130.03/6.27)
|   |   |   |   |   |   FeatureLabel-dep_head_det_the > 0: ACTOR (16.19/6.27)
|   |   |   |   |   FeatureLabel-hasPOS > 0: ACTOR (21.41/2.09)
|   |   |   |   FeatureLabel-hasNN > 0
|   |   |   |   |   FeatureVehicle-Class <= 0.487179
```

...