# java executing linux command

Tags: java, linux, bash, cat

I`m trying to execute linux commant 'cat' from java code, but it does not working.

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cat /home/roman/logs/*");
```

And it working well for cat of single file

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cat /home/roman/logs/mylog.log");
```

My question is how to cat all files on some dir from java ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Want to invoke a linux shell command from Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410741/want-to-invoke-a-linux-shell-command-from-java)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could put all files under the dir into a collection and iterate over it:

```
File[] files = dir.listFiles();
for (File f : files) {
  Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cat "+dir.getAbsolutePath()+File.separator+f.getName());
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't use `*` with the `exec()` command (you would need a shell). A solution could be to write a script and then `exec()` that script from your java application.

Answer (score 2):

Runtim.exec() does not use a shell to execute the command. Therefore the wildcard is not expanded. Try the solution explained in [Want to invoke a linux shell command from java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410741/want-to-invoke-a-linux-shell-command-from-java)