# executing unix commands from java using runtime class

Tags: java, unix, runtime.exec

```
Process log_remover = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("echo \"bleh\" > test.txt");
log_remover.waitFor();
log_remover.destroy();
```

this does nothing

```
Process node_creation = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cp -r ../HLR"+String.valueOf(count-1)+" ../HLR"+String.valueOf(count));
node_creation.waitFor();
node_creation.destroy();
```

however this works :S

Answer (score 1):

The redirection works only if a shell is used. Runtime.exec() does not use a shell.

See [Java Executing Linux Command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9993873/java-executing-linux-command)

Comment: hmmm yeah true.. thanks man.. the link helped out

Answer (score 1):

Redirection is handled by a shell, and you're not invoking a shell here, so you can't use redirection. Something like this, on the other hand, would work:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] {"sh",  "-c", "echo 'bleh' > text.txt"});
```

Note I've changed this to use the form of `exec()` that takes an array of Strings, as properly tokenizing quoted strings on a command line is something else that only the shell can do!

Comment: y have u put a -c @Ernest Friedman-Hill? if its for shell im using a korn shell

Comment: Process log_remover = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("log_remover.sh"); Why isnt this working

Comment: I don't know. Is `log_remover.sh` executable? Is it on your `PATH` ?

Answer (score 0):

Classic mistake I've seen many times before...

The first argument to `Runtime.getRuntime().exec()` is the *executable*, so your code is trying to execute a command literally called `echo \"bleh\" > test.txt`, but it should be trying to execute `echo`. Arguments to executables are passed in after the executable, like this:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("echo", new String[]{"bleh"});
```

Redirecting output is another story, because the *nix operator `>` is a shell thing. To replicate this in java you have to get the outputstream of the command and pump it to the inputstream of another process

Comment: find ./HLR3/LOGS -name '*.txt' -exec rm {} \;  how can i execute this @Bohemian

Comment: Process log_remover = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("log_remover.sh"); this doesnt work

Comment: use the absolute path, eg `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/usr/bin/log_remover.sh")` or whatever it is. The java exec environment isn't the same as your shell.