# Java runtime not able to run command on mac

Tags: java, macos, path, ffmpeg

I installed ffmpeg on mac through brew install. When i run ffmpeg command from terminal, it is running fine. But when i create a program in java and execute command like

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ffmpeg");
```

It is throwing IOException 
Cannot run program "ffmpeg":error=2, No such file or directory.
Any idea how to resolve it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Want to invoke a linux shell command from Java](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1410741/5221149)

Comment: tried with that option also, but did not work out.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the below code

```
String[] command = new String[]{"/bin/bash","-c","ffmpeg -version"};            
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
```