# Running ffprobe command on MAC through JAVA

Tags: java, bash, macos, executable-jar

I installed ffmpeg through brew in MAC OS and using its terminal the below command executes absolutely fine.

```
ffprobe -v quiet -print_format json -show_format -show_streams test.mp4
```

I have written the below code and it runs fine when running through "javac" and "java" command.

Code :

```
String[] strg = new String[]{"~/bin/bash","-c","ffprobe -v quiet -print_format json -show_format -show_streams /Users/qa/Desktop/666_Day01_Hr002.MP4"};
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(strg);
```

But when I am trying with JAR self executable, getting the below error.
`IOException Cannot run program "ffmpeg":error=2, No such file or directory`

Somebody asked the [same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38170325/java-runtime-not-able-to-run-command-on-mac), bit it did not help me in any way.

Please help me.

Comment: I created a .java file in MAC machine and compiled it and run it using JAVAC & JAVA command from terminal and it run with correct output.

The code is:

`String[] cmd = new String[]{"/bin/bash","-c","ffprobe -v quiet -print_format json -show_format -show_streams /Users/qa/Desktop/666_Day01_Hr002.MP4"};           
            Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);`
The same code from a self executable JAR is not running in MAC machine and giving the below error.

/bin/bash ffprobe Not a proper command.