# How to merge one file to another \ Linux

Tags: java, linux, cat

I am trying to append one text file to another by using linux commands from my Java program. I am completely new to Linux. I tried sorting and it works just fine, so I have no idea what I am doing wrong with using 'cat'.
Could you please review my code and help me figure out what I am doing wrong.

```
public static void mergeRecords(String fileName, String overflowFileName)
{
    String command = "cat " + overflowFileName + " >> " + fileName;
    try {
        Process r = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why you are calling a Linux command from java code. Why you do not use tha java classes?

Comment: Can ypu tell us what is happen if you run the program?

Comment: Because I was specifically asked by my professor to use Linux commands :) @Jens

Comment: Hi, the command looks fine, could you paste the error?

Comment: Nothing happens, the files are not being merged together at all. @Jens

Comment: The content from the overflow file doesn't appear in the "file"?

Comment: So file is unchanged? Try to append ` 2>&1` at the end of your command and all errors will be written to file, and you may be able to find the problem

Comment: @cohenjo just added getErrorStream() and this is the error that shows up:
cat: >>: No such file or directory

Comment: @useruser123 `overflow_file` must be an empty string then.

Comment: Looks like your arguments are empty... Could you print them before...

Comment: @Jezor it's not, I printed it out to see if that might be the case. The error is here:
cat: >>: No such file or directory

Comment: @cohenjo they're not empty. I even tried hard coding file names to test it but it still doesn't work

Comment: @useruser123 i refactored your code a little bit. If you print "command" string, what do you get?

Comment: @useruser123 wait a minute... are you executing your code on Linux?

Comment: @Jezor yes I am

Comment: @useruser123 are you sure your files exist? Your code works fine for me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Want to invoke a linux shell command from Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410741/want-to-invoke-a-linux-shell-command-from-java)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Runtime#exec` *is not a shell*.

This is a very common misconception. What you need to do is:

- create a `Process` with the command `cat file1 file2`,
- take the output of that process,
- dump that output into a file.

Hint: use a `ProcessBuilder`, this will make your job much easier.

Comment: Or just add [bash -c](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1410778/5922757) (if he's using `bash` of course).

Comment: Yep, this was the problem. As I said I'm completely new to Linux and on an assignment deadline so I didn't really do a lot of research. I used ProcessBuilder and now it works :) Thank you

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out, you should not use external commands to do something Java can easily do:

```
try (OutputStream existingFile = Files.newOutputStream(
    Paths.get(fileName),
    StandardOpenOption.WRITE,
    StandardOpenOption.APPEND)) {

    Files.copy(Paths.get(overflowFileName), existingFile);
}
```

Comment: Why the use of a `BufferedOutputStream`? To be honest, I have never seen  any difference in speed between this and a "classical" `OutputStream`, at least as far as file I/O is concerned...

Comment: FileOutputStream is analogous to C’s write(), while BufferedOutputStream is analogous to C’s fwrite(), so it’s good practice, usually.  But you made me curious, so I looked at the source of the Files class… and it is indeed doing its own buffering for both Files.copy(Path, OutputStream, options) and Files.copy(InputStream, Path, options).  Which means, for those two methods at least, BufferedOutputStream and BufferedInputStream are not needed.  I’ve removed it.