# Running command in cmd.exe via Eclipse RCP application

Tags: eclipse-rcp

I need to run a command in cmd.exe wherein, the command comes from my eclipse rcp application.
For example, I have a wizard in my application which accepts parameters of the command, and on clicking Finish button, the command should get executed.

Any help regarding how to access the cmd.exe from my eclipse rcp application would be of great help.

Comment: This is just the same as any Java program.

Answer (score 0):

as greg-449 said it is the same than in Java, see answers on [Want to invoke a linux shell command from Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410741/want-to-invoke-a-linux-shell-command-from-java)

Regards,