# How to run linux command from java

Tags: java

I'm trying to run a linux command (with pipes)

using something like:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("rpm -qa | grep "Uploader" | xargs rpm --queryformat "%{VERSION}" -q");
```

but i get as result only the output of the **"rpm -qa"**

can you help?

thanks

Comment: You could try putting your command in a script and calling that.  Java gets confused when there are multiple parameters.

Comment: Neither java nor rpm know about pipes. Shell knows about pipes. So your best bet is to wrap your pipe in a small shell script and execute that!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Want to invoke a linux shell command from Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410741/want-to-invoke-a-linux-shell-command-from-java)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only a shell understands pipes, you can invoke the shell with the command you want to run:

```
exec(new String[]{"/bin/sh", "-c", "rpm -qa | grep \"Uploader\" | xargs rpm --queryformat \"%{VERSION}\" -q"});
```