# How to run docker compose from Java application?

Tags: java, elasticsearch, docker-compose, logstash

I would like to run docker compose from my java code - for example when I transform my data into the right format run docker compose with logstash which will pour data to the elasticsearch.

How can I do that (also independently on the platform) ?

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Seems like an XY problem to me. Why is your Java application transforming data then poking logstash?

Comment: It is performing some logic like validating input etc. based on more complex rules, it is doable via logstash plugin written in ruby but since I am not so good at it I prefer Java way.

Comment: But logstash is a streaming log interpreter - it follows logs and groks them into ES. I don't understand how your approach works. I would expect your Java application to do the same - stream from some location and then transform and push into Logstash using a port based input.

Comment: Rather than have the java program spin up another docker container, it's more idiomatic to use `docker-compose` to bring up both containers at the same time and have the java program talk to the other program over the "network".

Answer (score 2):

I think in this case, you can use Test Containers.

Long story short. More details are in the documentation.
You can create easily docker compose which is based on `compose-test.yml`

```
public static DockerComposeContainer environment =
    new DockerComposeContainer(new File("src/test/resources/compose-test.yml"))
            .withExposedService("redis_1", REDIS_PORT)
            .withExposedService("elasticsearch_1", ELASTICSEARCH_PORT);
```

`compose-test.yml` looks like:

```
redis:
  image: redis
elasticsearch:
  image: elasticsearch
```

Here is the link to documentation:

https://www.testcontainers.org/usage/docker_compose.html

Comment: What dependency do I have to add in order to be able to use DockerComposeContainer ?

Comment: org.testcontainers : testcontainers: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.testcontainers/testcontainers

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to trigger the docker compose on the command line, you can issue a shell command from java. For an example, see [Want to invoke a linux shell command from Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410741/want-to-invoke-a-linux-shell-command-from-java).

Comment: Obviously OP does not want to trigger the command from the shell! He wants to use Java code from Eclipse or IntelliJ.