# How do I print the list of files and folders in a root directory in linux using java

Tags: java, linux, unix, processbuilder, runtime.exec

I am new to both Java and Linux, I was trying to use some `Runtime.exec()` commands that would allow my program to execute commands in Linux such as `"cd /mnt/"` and `"ls --group-directories-first"` to list files and directories contained in /mnt/ but I think I am making a problem with the execution.

I tried my code to only include the `"ls --group-directories-first"` and it worked like a charm, only problem was, it only listed subdirectories and files in the projects folder. I wanted to make my program go to /mnt/ first so I made my command line to a command array by using `exec(String[] cmdarray)` format as `process1 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"cd /mnt/","ls --group-directories-first"});` and when I ran it on linux, it just got executed without any printed runtime errors but also without any feedback/printed lines.

Here is my code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class linCom {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String s;
        Process p;

        try {
            p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ls --group-directories-first");
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
            while ((s = br.readLine()) != null)
                System.out.println("line: " + s);
            p.waitFor();
            System.out.println ("exit: " + p.exitValue());
            p.destroy();
        } catch (Exception e) {}


    }
}
```

This worked and printed out:

"line: DummyFolder1

line: linCom.class

line: linCom.java

exit: 0"

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class linCom {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String s;
        Process p;

        try {
            p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"cd /mnt/","ls --group-directories-first"});
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
            while ((s = br.readLine()) != null)
                System.out.println("line: " + s);
            p.waitFor();
            System.out.println ("exit: " + p.exitValue());
            p.destroy();
        } catch (Exception e) {}


    }
}
```

This just got executed with no printed lines.

I expected my program to just go to the /mnt/ directory and print out subdirectories and files on there, but it just got executed with no visible runtime errors and no printed lines.

I have looked at other entries but could not find any answer to my problem.

EDIT: I changed "no errors" with "no error messages" to make it clear that if program had any errors, I did not get any feedback about it.

Comment: Just for the record: **never** go with empty catch blocks. There is no point in ignoring errors. At least go "e.printStackTrace()" for example.

Comment: "This just got executed with no errors " ... how would you now if you suppress exceptions? But well, the point here is: you cant "combine" commands like that.

Comment: Open a terminal and type out those commands yourself. What is the output you get? Are you sure there are subdirectories in `/mnt`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's where the UNIX process model can be confusing.

What you have tries to run the program named `cd /mnt/` with the first parameter of `ls --group-directories-first` . Unix programs can be named anything (they're just filenames) but there's no program named `cd /mnt`.  And anyway, the cd operation is actually performed by  a shell, not as a forked/execed program.

You hope to run this shell command from your Java program: `cd /mnt/; ls --group-directories-first` .  The trouble is, [Java's `.exec()` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec-java.lang.String-)  does not give you a shell, so shell commands don't work.

You can try this instead. It's like running the shell command

```
/bin/sh -c "cd /mnt/; ls --group-directories-first"
```

With this, you start a shell, then tell it to run `-c`the command you want.

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"/bin/sh",
                                                   "-c",
                                                   "cd /mnt/; ls --group-directories-first"});
```

But it's quite dependent on the machine where your Java program runs, so be careful.

Reference: [How to invoke a Linux shell command from Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410741/how-to-invoke-a-linux-shell-command-from-java)

Comment: Thank you, that was exactly my problem and you solved it! Too bad I cannot vote as I have <15 points.

Answer (score 2):

Do not use an external process just to list files.  Java has plenty of ways to do that.  All of them are in the [Files](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html) class.  For example:

```
Path dir = Paths.get("/mnt");
try (Stream<Path> files = Files.list(dir).sorted(
    Comparator.comparing((Path p) -> !Files.isDirectory(p))
        .thenComparing(Comparator.naturalOrder()))) {

    files.forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you **really need** to use `Runtime.exec()`comands? That would make your code platafform dependent.

You could use `File.listFiles()`:

```
File folder = new File("/mnt");
for (File f : folder.listFiles()) {
    System.out.println(f.getName());
}
```

That would make the code less plataform dependent