# Java find out if Batch file ran successfully

Tags: java, batch-file

I'm running a Batch file from Java like so:

```
Runtime
    .getRuntime()
    .exec("cmd /c " + filepath);
```

Is there any way to find out if the Batch file ran successfully or failed from within Java?

Comment: How about checking the logs?

Comment: Is this a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410741/how-to-invoke-a-linux-shell-command-from-java

Comment: That very much depends on your definition of "success". you can of course check the RETURN CODE coming back when executing a command. But is that "enough" ... we dont know, as you didnt specify that part.

Comment: `exec` returns a [`Process`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html), which has an `.exitValue` and a `.getOutputStream` methods you can use to check the exit value and output of the command you executed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`Process`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html) instance that [`Runtime#exec(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec-java.lang.String-) constructs:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c " + filepath);
```

You can call [`Process#waitFor`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#waitFor--) which "causes the current thread to wait, if necessary, until the process represented by this Process object has terminated." Afterwords, see if it completed successfully with [`Process#exitValue`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#exitValue--).

You can also interact with the process by fetching its input and output streams:

```
InputStream inputStream = p.getInputStream(), errorStream = p.getErrorStream();
OutputStream outputStream = p.getOutputStream();
```