# Using checkpassword-pam from Java

Tags: java, posix, pam

I'd like to use [checkpassword-pam](https://linux.die.net/man/8/checkpassword-pam) in a java application. It's a very simple executable that reads a username and password from fd 3 and then verifies it.
The protocol is described [here](http://cr.yp.to/checkpwd/interface.html).

In a shell you'd use it like this:

```
# echo -e "username\0password\0timestamp\0" \
| checkpassword-pam -s SERVICE \
--debug --stdout -- /usr/bin/id 3<&0
```

How would I do this from a java application ?
I'm sure it can't be done through standard Java, but perhaps accessing posix api via jna...

Comment: You can run programs using `ProcessBuilder`/`Runtime.getRuntime().exec()`. You can then control `stdin`/`stdout`.

Answer (score 0):

In order to do what you want you can use the [Runtime](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Runtime.html) class, using `Runtime.getRuntime()`, and the `exec` method of the runtime to run a command from inside your Java program. From this, you can use the [Process](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Process.html) class to control the standard input and output of that shell command, essentially simulating that the user typed in the command from their console. You can look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410741/how-to-invoke-a-linux-shell-command-from-java) for more help

Comment: The question is specifically about writing to a non-standard file descriptor (3) and not stdin.

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question: a simple shell command can redirect fd 3 to stdin.

```
    try {
        Process p = new ProcessBuilder("/bin/sh", "-c" , "exec /usr/bin/checkpassword-pam -s sshd 3<&0 /usr/bin/id").redirectErrorStream(true).start();
        OutputStream os = p.getOutputStream();
        os.write(userName.getBytes(Charset.defaultCharset()));
        os.write(0);
        os.write(password.getBytes(Charset.defaultCharset()));
        os.write(0);
        os.close();
        p.waitFor(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        if (p.exitValue() == 0) {
            logger.info("authenticated user {}", IOUtils.read(p.getInputStream()).trim());
            result = true;
        } else {
            logger.info("authenticated failed for user {}", userName);
            result = false;
        }
    } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
        logger.error("failed to authenticate user {}",  userName, e);
        result = false;
    }
```